# Firebase Database crash SQLiteDatabaseLockedException

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm getting this crash on few devices, but only on Android 4.

I'm on Firebase Android SDK <strike>10.2.1</strike> 11.0.2. Deferring updating to the latest version because it forces update of Google Play Services as well, and many users continue to remain on older GPS versions.

Is anybody else seeing this problem?

**Update:** This was working earlier. Crashes started after I upgraded from Firebase SDK 9.4.0 to 10.2.1, and compileSdkVersion 23 to 25. Crash only happens on Android 4.4 (Kitkat 19)

*Updated* Exception:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.mz.run(Unknown Source)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by o.kD: Failed to gain exclusive lock to Firebase Database's offline persistence. This generally means you are using Firebase Database from multiple processes in your app. Keep in mind that multi-process Android apps execute the code in your Application class in all processes, so you may need to avoid initializing FirebaseDatabase in your Application class. If you are intentionally using Firebase Database from multiple processes, you can only enable offline persistence (i.e. call setPersistenceEnabled(true)) in one of them.
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.nb.zzN(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.nb.(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.mx.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.qd.zzgQ(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.qu.zzHg(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.qu.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.qv.run(Unknown Source)
       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
Caused by android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is locked (code 5): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(SQLiteConnection.java)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:893)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForString(SQLiteConnection.java:638)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setJournalMode(SQLiteConnection.java:320)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setWalModeFromConfiguration(SQLiteConnection.java:294)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:215)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:829)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:814)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:709)
       at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:1039)
       at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:256)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.nb.zzN(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.nb.(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.mx.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.qd.zzgQ(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.qu.zzHg(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.qu.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.qv.run(Unknown Source)
       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I do have multiple processes in the app, but using the following code to abort Application.onCreate for sub processes.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    if (FirebaseApp.getApps(this).isEmpty()) {
        // No firebase apps; we are in a non-main process
        return;
    }

    // Firebase init and other custom logic
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: Enable `multidex`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Could you explain why multidex is the problem here? This crash is not repeatable for me, and my only option is to test in production.

Comment: @NizamMohideen Even i am facing the same issue . did you found any solution for this.

Answer (score 5):

There is no SQLiteDatabaseLockedException in Firebase. This [SQLiteDatabaseLockedException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabaseLockedException.html) is thrown when you are using a `SQLite` database with Android and the database engine is unable to acquire a database lock that is needs to do its job.

> If the statement is a [COMMIT] or occurs outside of an explicit transaction, then you can retry the statement. If the statement is not a [COMMIT] and occurs within a explicit transaction then you should rollback the transaction before continuing.

**Edit:** With the new edit of your detailed stack trace, i see what the error is. The error is occuring when you are setting `setPersistenceEnabled(true)`. This must be done before doing anything else with your `firebaseDatabase` object. So, i recomand you using the following code:

```
public class HelperClass {
    private static FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    public static FirebaseDatabase getDatabase() {
        if (firebaseDatabase == null) {
            firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            firebaseDatabase.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
        }
        return firebaseDatabase;
    }
}
```

Comment: The crash is indeed coming from Firebase Database. Got a more detailed stack trace which is updated in my question.

Comment: Now that I know it is a confirmed Firebase Database issue, I have more clues. This was a working piece of code, and the crashes started after I upgraded from Firebase SDK 9.4.0 to 10.2.1. Crashes continued after upgrading Firebase to 11.0.2 as well. Google Play Services is also at 11.0.2 now.

Comment: I have a singleton FirebaseManager where the first thing I do is setPersistenceEnabled, so that may not be the problem. Anyway, this was working earlier, so not suspecting the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152929/discussion-between-nizam-mohideen-and-alex-mamo).